# Waiting for user response in the App Delegate before viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-location

I have Latitude/Longitude check and question asked from app delegate as the latitude and longitude needs to be set and a piece of code needs to be run in app delegate before the `viewDidLoad` runs in the View controller since I have a set of labels/etc that depend on the code run in app delegate with the latitude and longitude

At the moment the question gets asked and it goes straight into `viewDidLoad` before receiving user input.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: A duplicate of your earlier question [Location Services in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228844/location-services-in-ios) with even less information that the original.

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate of that. I get what you're asking @user3328028 and I'm answering now.

Comment: P.S. People mark down questions way too often on this site. I added +1 to your question to bring it up to zero because I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go straight to the `viewDidLoad` of your first view controller. That's not an option.

If anything, you could delay showing the elements of the view until the user selects the option you ask for in your app delegate.  Perhaps add a replicate of your launch image over the view during `viewDidLoad` to block the elements underneath, then when the user makes their decision in the alert presented by the app delegate, trigger a method in the view controller to unhide the elements.

Comment: The next time someone down votes this, I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: should be zero, made it